# Grails JSON array

Tags: json, grails, groovy

I'm converting a list of Foo objects to a JSON string. I need to parse the JSON string back into a list of Foos. However in the following example, parsing gives me a list of JSONObjects instead of Foos.

**Example**

```
List list = [new Foo("first"), new Foo("second")]
def jsonString = (list as JSON).toString()

List parsedList = JSON.parse(jsonString) as List
println parsedList[0].getClass() // org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.json.JSONObject
```

How can I parse it into Foos instead?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had a look at the API docs for JSON and there doesn't appear to be any way to parse to a JSON string to a specific type of object.

So you'll just have to write the code yourself to convert each `JSONObject` to a `Foo`. Something like this should work:

```
import grails.converters.JSON
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.json.*

class Foo {
  def name

  Foo(name) {
    this.name = name
  }

  String toString() {
    name
  }
}


List list = [new Foo("first"), new Foo("second")]
def jsonString = (list as JSON).toString()

List parsedList = JSON.parse(jsonString)

// Convert from a list of JSONObject to a list of Foo
def foos = parsedList.collect {JSONObject jsonObject ->
    new Foo(name: jsonObject.get("name"))
}
```

A more general solution would be to add a new static `parse` method such as the following to the `JSON` metaClass, that tries to parse the JSON string to a List of objects of a particular type:

```
import grails.converters.JSON
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.json.*

class Foo {
  def name

  Foo(name) {
    this.name = name
  }

  String toString() {
    name
  }
}

List list = [new Foo("first"), new Foo("second")]
def jsonString = (list as JSON).toString()


List parsedList = JSON.parse(jsonString)

// Define the new method
JSON.metaClass.static.parse = {String json, Class clazz ->

    List jsonObjs = JSON.parse(json)

    jsonObjs.collect {JSONObject jsonObj ->

        // If the user hasn't provided a targetClass read the 'class' proprerty in the JSON to figure out which type to convert to
        def targetClass = clazz ?: jsonObj.get('class') as Class
        def targetInstance = targetClass.newInstance()        

        // Set the properties of targetInstance
        jsonObj.entrySet().each {entry ->

            if (entry.key != "class") {
                targetInstance."$entry.key" = entry.value
            }
        }
        targetInstance
    }

}

// Try the new parse method
List<Foo> foos = JSON.parse(jsonString, Foo)

// Confirm it worked
assert foos.every {Foo foo -> foo.class == Foo && foo.name in ['first', 'second'] }
```

You can try out the code above in the groovy console. A few warnings

- I have only performed very limited testing on the code above
- There are two JSON classes in the latest Grails release, I'm assuming you're using the one that is not deprecated

Comment: Would it be possible to inject the attributes of each jsonObj directoy into the foo.properties field for each new instance of Foo?

Comment: @Ali G - No, I think `.properties` is only writeable for Grails domain objects. For regular Groovy objects, I think `.properties` is read-only.

Comment: Thanks Don. The generic approach is very nice.

Comment: Fair point, Don - I was making some big assumptions there, I guess!

Comment: How do you deal with dates and nullable values?

Answer (score 4):

If you are doing this in a Grails controller, and Foo IS indeed a domain object, don't forget that armed with your JSON map, you can also do:

```
List list = [new Foo("first"), new Foo("second")]
def jsonString = (list as JSON).toString()

List parsedList = JSON.parse(jsonString) as List
Foo foo = new Foo()
bindData(foo, parsedList[0]);
```

Comment: or even better

Foo foo = new Foo(parsedList[0])

Answer (score 4):

I've taken this code and extended it to work with nested structures.  It relies on a 'class' attribute existing in the JSON.  If there's a better way by now in Grails please let me know.

```
     // The default JSON parser just creates generic JSON objects.  If there are nested

    // JSON arrays they are not converted to theirs types but are left as JSON objects
    // This converts nested JSON structures into their types.
    // IT RELIES ON A PROPERTY 'class' that must exist in the JSON tags
    JSON.metaClass.static.parseJSONToTyped = {def jsonObjects ->

        def typedObjects = jsonObjects.collect {JSONObject jsonObject ->
            if(!jsonObject.has("class")){
                throw new Exception("JSON parsing failed due to the 'class' attribute missing: " + jsonObject)
            }

            def targetClass = grailsApplication.classLoader.loadClass(jsonObject.get("class"))
            def targetInstance = targetClass.newInstance()

            // Set the properties of targetInstance
            jsonObject.entrySet().each {entry ->
                // If the entry is an array then recurse
                if(entry.value instanceof org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.json.JSONArray){
                    def typedSubObjects = parseJSONToTyped(entry.value)
                    targetInstance."$entry.key" = typedSubObjects
                }
                else if (entry.key != "class") {
                    targetInstance."$entry.key" = entry.value
                }
            }

            targetInstance
        }

        return typedObjects
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Grails 2.5, this is possible:

```
Period test = new Period()
test.periodText = 'test'
String j = test as JSON
def p = JSON.parse(j)
test = p.asType(Period)
println(test.periodText)
```

Output:

```
test
```

I am unsure of when it became an option.