# how to parse json using groovy

Tags: json, grails, groovy

I want to parse JSON data which is coming in like:

```
{
   "212315952136472": {
      "id": "212315952136472",
      "name": "Ready",
      "picture": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/195762_212315952136472_4343686_s.jpg",
      "link": "http://www.hityashit.com/movie/ready",
      "likes": 5,
      "category": "Movie",
      "description": "Check out the reviews of Ready on  http://www.hityashit.com/movie/ready"
   }
}
```

The code I am using is:

```
JSONElement userJson = JSON.parse(jsonResponse)
userJson.data.each {
    Urls = it.link
}
```

But I am not able to get anything assigned to `Urls`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

That response is a Map, with a single element with key '212315952136472'. There's no 'data' key in the Map. If you want to loop through all entries, use something like this:

```
JSONObject userJson = JSON.parse(jsonResponse)
userJson.each { id, data -> println data.link }
```

If you know it's a single-element Map then you can directly access the `link`:

```
def data = userJson.values().iterator().next()
String link = data.link
```

And if you knew the id (e.g. if you used it to make the request) then you can access the value more concisely:

```
String id = '212315952136472'
...
String link = userJson[id].link
```

Comment: Burt, what am I supposed to import to make the first example code block work? I figured out i need `import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.json.JSONObject` but then it fails stating "No such property: JSON"

Comment: Got it - [from here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2673558/2067690). It's `import grails.converters.JSON`

Answer (score 84):

Have you tried using [JsonSlurper](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html)?

Example usage:

```
def slurper = new JsonSlurper()
def result = slurper.parseText('{"person":{"name":"Guillaume","age":33,"pets":["dog","cat"]}}')

assert result.person.name == "Guillaume"
assert result.person.age == 33
assert result.person.pets.size() == 2
assert result.person.pets[0] == "dog"
assert result.person.pets[1] == "cat"
```

Comment: This is for Groovy 1.8 and later only.

Comment: Awesome! You may need to `import groovy.json.JsonSlurper`

Comment: This does not answer the question, as the question has a dynamic id (like `212315952136472`) as part of the path. Could you please update your example to use the question's data? Thanks!

Comment: @NicolasRaoul  `def result = slurper.parseText(jsonResponse); assert result['212315952136472'].link == 'http://www.example.com/movie/ready'`

Answer (score 6):

You can convert JSON to the desired type in Groovy using `as` operator:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

String json = '''
{
  "name": "John",  
  "age": 20
}
'''

def person = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json) as Person 

with(person) {
    assert name == 'John'
    assert age == 20
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def jsonFile = new File('File Path');
JsonSlurper jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper();

def parseJson = jsonSlurper.parse(jsonFile)
String json = JsonOutput.toJson(parseJson)

def prettyJson = JsonOutput.prettyPrint(json)
println(prettyJson)
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing with this unique number is a bit tricky.

If you know this value, easy

```
stage('Test Groovy JSON parsing') {
    steps {
        script {
            def userJson = readJSON file: 'myJsonFile.json'

            def keyList = userJson['212315952136472'].keySet()
            echo "${keyList}"   // ['id', 'name', 'picture', 'link', 'likes', 'category', 'description']
            
            echo "${userJson['212315952136472'].name}"  // Ready
            echo "${userJson['212315952136472'].link}"  // http://www.hityashit.com/movie/ready
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't know this number, you could walk through the JSON

```
userJson.each { key, value ->
    echo "Walked through key $key and value $value"
}
```

check also the documentation at [Jenkins Read JSON from File](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readjson-read-json-from-files-in-the-workspace)