# jmeter assertion to validate json schema

Tags: json, jmeter, assertions

I'm currently testing a web application which outputs json. I want to make sure that the JSON is valid. I do not want to validate its content. How can I implement a assertion in jmeter to make sure that the json response is valid?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use beanshell assertion, jsr223 assertion or bsf assertion if you want to use groovy:

- [BeanShell Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Assertion)
- [JSR223 Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion)
- [BSF Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BSF_Assertion)

and parse the response using some json parser:

- [how to parse json using groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688090/how-to-parse-json-using-groovy)
- http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2011/04/groovy-goodness-parse-json-with.html

Jmeter will provide to your script the previous sampler response as a script variable.

Note that this can impact performance of your test plan as it's rather costly.

Regards

Answer (score 4):

I normally use [javascript BSF Assertion](http://fabiouechi.blogspot.com.br/2012/04/jmeter-using-bsf-assertion-to-fail.html).
Since JSON are javascript objects you can try to eval the response in a try-catch block and in case it fails you can explicitly fail the previous SampleResult.

```
try {
   eval('var response = ' + prev.getResponseDataAsString());
} catch(e) {
      prev.setSuccessful(false);
      prev.setResponseMessage("Invalid response. Expected a valid JSON.");
}
```