# Jmeter JSON Path Assertion

Tags: json, performance, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Below is my JSON response data, I need to do assertion using the below response. I tried in many ways to write JSON path & Expected Value. Always assertion fails. What I want is please help to write the path and expected value for the below data

```
{
    "statusCode": 200,
    "statusMessage": "Success",
    "errorMessage": "",
    "responseData": {
        "id": 15,
        "userName": "partner@tarento.com",
        "firstName": "tarento",
        "lastName": "test1",
        "phoneNumber": "1234567812",
        "email": "partner@tarento.com",
        "password": "",
        "city": "",
        "agentList": [
            {
                "id": 37,
                "userName": "Rahul.antonyRaj@tarento.com",
                "firstName": "Sanjay",
                "lastName": "rahul",
                "phoneNumber": "7411269480",
                "email": "Rahul.antonyRaj@tarento.com",
                "password": "",
                "active": true
            },
            {
                "id": 68,
                "userName": "jinesh.sumedhan@tareto.com",
                "firstName": "jinesh",
                "lastName": "sumedhan",
                "phoneNumber": "9400993826",
                "email": "jinesh.sumedhan@tareto.com",
                "password": "",
                "active": true
            },
            {
                "id": 108,
                "userName": "a.sanjayrahul@gmail.com",
                "firstName": "Rahul",
                "lastName": "Antony",
                "phoneNumber": "9994590241",
                "email": "a.sanjayrahul@gmail.com",
                "password": "",
                "active": true
            },
            {
                "id": 304,
                "userName": "a.sanjayrajish@gmail.com",
                "firstName": "Agent",
                "lastName": "Agent",
                "phoneNumber": "9025699716",
                "email": "a.sanjayrajish@gmail.com",
                "password": "",
                "active": true
            }
        ],
        "roleName": "admin",
        "sessionKey": "435tnerLt9813942160478oDse46345635#1",
        "partner": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Tarento",
            "cityList": [
                "bangalore",
                "mumbai"
            ],
            "phone": "1234567812",
            "url": ""
        },
        "isActive": true,
        "isDeleted": false,
        "roleId": 1,
        "countryCode": "",
        "tags": [
            {
                "tagId": 1,
                "name": "all",
                "description": "this is default tag of all driver."
            },
            {
                "tagId": 2,
                "name": "airport",
                "description": ""
            },
            {
                "tagId": 3,
                "name": "street",
                "description": "any text message"
            },
            {
                "tagId": 255,
                "name": "night",
                "description": "night"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I received the following response

[image]

[image]

Comment: Provide more details like what is the json path you've written? what is the expected value in your example?

Comment: Please check the below images,my test plan & and its response

Comment: Did you try to remove square brackets?

Comment: Change `[200]` to `200` in Expected value.

Comment: Removing square brackets works,but how should I will know the JSON path assertion got passed ?

Comment: @Sreenivas You won't be getting error like the one in your last screenshot.

Comment: Thank you guys it worked and I understood the concept

Answer (score 4):

For start following JSONPath Assertion will test your `statusCode`

```
$.statusCode
```

put `200` to Expected Value of JSONPath Assertion.

This one is for `userName`

```
$.responseData.userName
```

Easy, isn't it? See [Parsing JSON](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) guide for more useful examples and how-tos.

Comment: Please check the below images,my test plan & and its response

Comment: Add your `JSONPath` assertion **as a child** of your HTTP Request and remove brackets around 200

Answer (score 4):

I found the **JSR223 Assertion** with script language `javascript` to be the easiest. at least if you have knowledge in java and javascript. And no need to add any plugins.

My working code in detail:

```
var json = JSON.parse(SampleResult.getResponseDataAsString());
if (json.statusCode != 200) {
    AssertionResult.setFailureMessage("" 
        + json.statusCode 
        + " " + json.statusMessage
        + " " + json.errorMessage);
    AssertionResult.setFailure(true);
}
```

Comment: I used your code, but getting assertion failure:
Assertion failure message:javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: JSON for class: Script1

Answer (score 3):

I personally prefer to use BSF PostProcessor in coupling with Groovy language. Example of how to parse JSON with Groovy you can find here [how to parse json using groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688090/how-to-parse-json-using-groovy)

Comment: Hi thank you for responding me,I'm new to Jmeter and im not that comfortable with Post Processor could you share step by step how to check the assertion for json data

Comment: Hi, I will be happy to help you but can you please show what you have tried so far?

Comment: Please check the above images,my test plan & and its response

Comment: Why do you edit my answer?? Are you sure you wanted to answer me but not @Dmitriy T?

Comment: Reverted to the original post, why don't you update your question, @Sreenivas?

Comment: @Dmitriy T - sorry for editing ur answer .@Can I have posted my test plan and response. I need correct JSON path and expected value based on the above JSON data