# How to convert java.lang.String to json in groovy

Tags: groovy

My java.lang.String is of form

```
 [[{"ABC":{"total":0,"failed":0,"skipped":0}}], [{"BCD": {"total":0,"failed":0,"skipped":0}}]]
```

How to convert this to json in groovy?

Comment: That looks like JSON already...

Comment: maybe you want to parse the string to objects? what's your final goal?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to parse json using groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688090/how-to-parse-json-using-groovy)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Parsing json from string with built-in groovy tools is done with `groovy.json.JsonSlurper`. You can check the documentation at [here](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html).

Here's how your example json can be accessed, just like groovy nested map:

```
def str = '[[{"ABC":{"total":0,"failed":0,"skipped":0}}], [{"BCD": {"total":0,"failed":0,"skipped":0}}]]'
def parser = new JsonSlurper()
def json = parser.parseText(str)
assert json[0][0].ABC.total == 0
assert json[0][0].ABC.failed == 0
assert json[0][0].ABC.skipped == 0
assert json[1][0].BCD.total == 0
assert json[1][0].BCD.failed == 0
assert json[1][0].BCD.skipped == 0
```