# Groovy scripting

Tags: groovy, katalon-studio

I am working with API automation in groovy.

I have created an HTTP post request. 
I got the response in json format as below:

```
{"Response":"result","data":"234556667","status":"6"}
```

Now I want to extract only the "data" which will be dynamic always.

Can someone help me with this, please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to parse json using groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688090/how-to-parse-json-using-groovy)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have to Parse Data from JSON. In Katalon Studio you can write Java code too just you need to make sure you are importing right package.
Refer articles -
https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/parse_json_responses.html#verify-if-a-key-is-present-in-json
or
 [How to parse JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the response. Try something like this

```
def response = '{"Response":"result","data":"234556667","status":"6"}'
def parsed = new JsonSlurper().parseText(response)
println parsed.get("data")
```

It will always print the value of the key "data".